# Google Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL database connection from QGIS for third parties

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, qgis

I have a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database in which I can connect by using SSL and by entering my IP address in allowed connection settings. However, I do not want to list all the IP addresses that is going to connect to this database (because I do not know all the IP addresses). I have around 15 people which I want them to login to my database using QGIS and they should be able to change the data as this is a research. Security is not a big issue as this database will be online for a very short period of time. What connection method can you suggest? The users are not very proficient so I need to setup everything.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing fine.

I would like to suggest to set the connections with the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) as it will provide the security needed without using ssl or the need of authorize any network. so basically the set up is to:

1. Enable the API
2. Install the proxy client on your local machine
3. Determine how you will authenticate the proxy
4. If required by your authentication method, create a service account

Also you can find the steps on ["Connecting to Cloud SQL from external applications"](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#proxy)

Hope this works for you as I have never used it with QGIS but I believe that as you are using a proxy it won't be hard from there to use it with QGIS as if you connected to a local server.